# Google geocoding with latlang results with no Country Type

Tags: maps

I am trying to do something tricky:
1) I use the geocoder with LatLng that I have of a city (let's say Atlanta, GA)
2) I get the results and I walk over them to save the LatLng of all the types (i.e.: street, city, county, state, country);
3) For some reason - Google does not supply County = USA within the results["types"]

Can anyone help ? here is how the results looks like:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=33.5997220,-117.6994440&v=2&sensor=false

Noticed that there are results:

1. "types" : [ "street_address" ]
2. "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
3. "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
4. "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
5. "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]

But no Country

Thanks in advance,
Nisan

Answer (score 0):

I think the country name *is* returned, that you just overlooked it.  When I look at the URL you mentioned, I see this fragment:

```
{
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
```